# Google charts - page does not load when chart function called

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using Google Charts for the first time. I have copied their basic example of pie chart into my page and have included Google jsapi in my header.

I have added the following code to my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and draws it.
function drawChart() {

  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Items', '# Items'],
    ['New', eval(new_items)],
    ['Current', eval(cur_items)],
    ['Retired', eval(ret_items)]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('item_mix')).
  draw(data, {title:"Items Status Mix"});   
  }

</script>
```

When I load the page it all works OK, chart shows and values for my variables confirm with the data.

I then wrap the Google code in my own function and call loadHQCharts(); at the end of the main script.

```
<div id="item_mix"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function loadHQCharts() {
   // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});    
   .
   . 
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  DO STUFF HERE...
  loadHQCharts();
});
</script>
```

The page loads and then it goes blank with an empty BODY and no errors in inspect/Firebug. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Does your example with `function loadHQCharts()` works without any other code? I run it without problem. Do you have any other div elements on the page?

Comment: Hi Anto, thanks for the reply. I am loading it inside of Wordpress / Avada theme if it helps. I cannot still now understand why, when the code is outside of a function it loads perfectly, when inside the function it blows the BODY away (as if page reloads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` wrapper and call `loadHQCharts` directly, it is supposed to work so.

Or remove the `google.setOnLoadCallback` function and add the `callback` parameter to the first line:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawChart});
  //remove: //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: Hi Vortex, thanks for the reply, but I do not think I was clear in my explanation. I call the function as "loadHQCharts();". I have amended above. I am still stuck with this, as I get no errors...

Comment: @TheRealPapa ok, it seems that `$(document).ready` and `setOnLoadCallback` don't work together, I proposed 2 solutions in my edited answer.